# Display images in c++

Tags: c++, atmega

I want to make a program that will display pictures (eventually video with sound too) on a small lcd screen, I wan't to use an atmega 328 chip with an sd card to store the images. Any help that would point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what interface the screen uses.

Generally text LCDs have serial interfaces http://dioioib.blogspot.com/2010/02/easy-lcd-screen-interface-on-atmega32.html or http://www.engineersgarage.com/embedded/avr-microcontroller-projects/interface-lcd-circuit/ with a few control codes for flashing/reversed characters.

I think video might be a bit optomistic with that chip - although I have done video test pattern generators by just bit-twiddling an output line.

ps. Haven't tried it but this [SoftwareVGA](http://neil.franklin.ch/Projects/SoftVGA/) looks interesting

Comment: Thank you for your fast response, What chip would you suggest for the video. Could you give me examples of the interface the screens might use and What is a good interface to look for?

Comment: @Cjueden: That sort of question probably belongs on electronics.se

Comment: @Martin: That SoftwareVGA thing does look interesting, but I'm inclined to distrust anyone who calls FPGA development tools awful and thinks he could do better if only the bitstream format was documented.  And the claim that he's driving a 20MHz signal out of PIO of an AVR w/16MHz clock.... plus sync signals with phase shift?  Color me skeptical.